# Is it possible to manipulate my WCDMA modem's code?

Tags: networking, modem

I have a WCDMA data card (WCDMA modem) that is used for Internet connectivity. Unfortunately it has been designed so proprietary that I cannot connect to any WCDMA other than the one who branded my modem. In fact, the software along with the modem has options related to operator selection disabled.

Is there any way I can get around this problem by changing config files located in the installation path or is it impossible to do so because the operation has been hardcoded in the device driver?

The reason for this is that the operator sold me the modem at an even much more expensive price compared with other modems. Then, I found it could only connect to one operator from which I purchased the modem. Screen shot was added for more clarification.

[image]

Comment: It is usually not only the software installed on your computer that is locked to one cell phone provider. It is the firmware in the modem that is locked down. This is called SIM-Lock. The provider can remove the lock after get paid extra.

Comment: But they wouldn't do that. Can't I somehow tweak its firmware or something?

Comment: There are companies in internet saying that they can remove SIM locks, just google them.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong dude. In fact, my device only recognizes SIMs from one operator. It also has disabled the option to search and register on other operator networks. Now, do you think there would be a way for me to communicate directly with the device or change software behavior?

Comment: That is just what SIM lock is: accept only SIM card from one provider. Usually this provider sell the hardware at extrem low prices, and try to make profit when you use the SIM.